# encrypt videos using eme clear key for cloud storage

Tags: encryption, cloud

Since the big cloud providers offer storage ever more cheaply, I am looking to move my media collection into the cloud. However, being aware of the privacy related issues I want to use encryption. My idea is to convert the videos into an encrypted webm format, and to use encrypted media extensions with a clear key content decryption module to play those videos in any modern browser. Is this a viable option? Has this been implemented before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is a viable option and It is implemented (but only can be decrypt using EME in chrome and chromium). The RFC of webM encryption is a draft and You can read the draft in the [webmproject page](http://wiki.webmproject.org/encryption/webm-encryption-rfc), also, to encrypt a webm video You can use the [webm_crypt tool](https://code.google.com/p/webm/source/browse/webm_crypt/?repo=webm-tools)